# Stop UIPageViewController at edge of screen

Tags: ios, swipe, uipageviewcontroller, edge-detection

As I am swiping between two views, the views follow the finger and exceeding the edge of the screen and finally bounces back to the edge screen when I release my finger.

Is there a way to make the views stop exactly at the edge?

Answer (score -1):

I found the anser by googling some more.

Here is the article that solves my problem: http://www.lukaszielinski.de/blog/posts/2014/03/26/restrict-panning-of-uipageviewcontroller-to-certain-area/